# asp.net load website in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have a few websites on my windows 2003/IIS 6.0 machine

One of the sites is publicly visible and the others are private (can browse locally - 192.168.1 address)

I would like to display the private site on a page of the public site but not with an iframe.

When I tried an iframe, the client browser tries to find the web site - which is not publicly visible

Is there a way to load the home page from the code behind (C#/VB.NET)?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just create another virtual directory under your public site that points at the 'private' site and access it that way?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest) in your public site's code to get the page content from the private site, then inline that into your response. You'll have to strip off everything but the content you're interested in (just what's in the  tag, for example).